# Ember.js + AddThis error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, ember.js, addthis

I am attempting to add the AddThis widget to an ember.js app. I am using basic code taken directly from addthis.com:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51ddaec37ede7c28"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

...and getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" from http://ct1.addthis.com/static/r07/core085.js on line 2.

I have asked support but have had no luck yet. Any ideas as to what is causing this would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Edit: I currently have the code above in a template in the app.

Comment: and you sure that the console point that the error is in that file?

Comment: Well all of that code is in line 2… Can you get an unminified version to test?

Comment: Yes I am certain. The console is referencing that line on that document with this error.

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately, unless things have changed, i don't think i can... http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/1207012-unminified-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a deeper look at the [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) widget and IMHO the code loaded from the script does some *nasty* things like creating a `script` tag nor an `iframe` etc. and being inside a `handlebars` template the DOM manipulations that the widget script does won't work in tandem with `ember.js`, unless the team behind [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) does something to make there widget more integration friendly.

So I had a look at some alternative sharing widgets, and [sharethis](http://sharethis.com/) does basically the same as [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) but with one big difference - I got easily working with `ember.js`

Basically what I've done was to create a view for the widget, and inside the `didInsertElement` the widget initialization is called:

```
App.WidgetView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'widget',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    stLight.options({publisher: "ur-733dae74-7b06-4fef-3f54-f60dce5ce03e", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});
  }
});
```

Then in another template the widget can be easily used by simply doing:

```
{{view App.WidgetView}}
```

The `widget` template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="widget">
  <span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
  <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
  <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
  <span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
  <span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
  <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span> 
</script>
```

Have a look here for a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/axihur/11/edit).

**Disclaimer**: Although my answer does not fix directly your problem, but maybe it helps you take a different approach by using a different sharing widget, because I guess you won't abandon `ember.js` only because some obscure programmed widget does not work correctly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I think it will! I am going to put this into practice ASAP! Thanks so much @intuitivepixel

Comment: I have it installed and it is working for the most part! Thanks!

However, I am getting this error now "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Still, much closer than AddThis. Thanks!

Any idea what it would be trying to read but can't?

Comment: @MelArlo hmm, I guess it would be helpfull to see your code to find the problem, or better you could post another question with example code prefereable in a jsbin, so it would be easier to debug

Comment: I think you're right... I will post a new question if needed. We may have solved it and if so I will post a question and answer. Thanks again for the head start!

Comment: Turns out the issue was asynchronous loading through Ember.js. Moving the inclusion of the ShareThis script to inside the didInsertElement call on the view has it working! :D

Comment: -1 for recommending ShareThis. Check out [this](https://benmarshall.me/sharethis-slowing-down-site/) blog post about the nasty things that ShareThis does.