# Mootools "Cannot read property 'call" of undefined"

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've got a website that is using MooTools. I've been getting the following errror, but can't figure out what is causing it. I've had very little luck tracing it out. Does anyone know what this might be? I haven't been able to find anything on the web about it.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined mootools-core.js:4497
>   condition mootools-core.js:4497
>   defn mootools-core.js:4511

Stackoverflow has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580457/ember-js-addthis-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-call-of-und) question, but it does not relate as far as I can tell. Ideas?

#### Update

Having looked at this a bit more, the cause of the error is still mysterious. The offending line in my code is an addEvent call:

```
            window.addEvent('load', preloader(preload));
```

The variable `preload` is an array of image urls. And the callback `preloader` is a method that preloads the images specified in `preload`. Here's the preloader method:

```
/**
 * Event callback that preloads images 
 */
function preloader(images) {
   var img;
   if ( images ) {
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = images[i];
      }
   }
}
```

The line of mootools code specified by the error is this:

```
addEvent: function(type, fn){
    var events = this.retrieve('events', {});
    if (!events[type]) events[type] = {keys: [], values: []};
    if (events[type].keys.contains(fn)) return this;
    events[type].keys.push(fn);
    var realType = type,
        custom = Element.Events[type],
        condition = fn,
        self = this;
    if (custom){
        if (custom.onAdd) custom.onAdd.call(this, fn, type);
        if (custom.condition){
            condition = function(event){
//error here--> if (custom.condition.call(this, event, type)) return fn.call(this, event);
                return true;
            };
        }
        if (custom.base) realType = Function.from(custom.base).call(this, type);
    }
    var defn = function(){
        return fn.call(self);
    };
    var nativeEvent = Element.NativeEvents[realType];
    if (nativeEvent){
        if (nativeEvent == 2){
            defn = function(event){
                event = new DOMEvent(event, self.getWindow());
                if (condition.call(self, event) === false) event.stop();
            };
        }
        this.addListener(realType, defn, arguments[2]);
    }
    events[type].values.push(defn);
    return this;
},
```

Comment: Do you have much code in the page? Can you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

Er. you are not passing a function as callback.

this:

```
window.addEvent('load', preloader(preload));

/**
 * Event callback that preloads images 
 */
function preloader(images) {
   var img;
   if ( images ) {
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = images[i];
      }
   }
}
```

it will essentially invoke the `preloader` function immediately, not `onload` - and it will try to bind the event to the result of the `preloader` function, which does not return anything at all.

when the interpreter sees `preloader(preload)`, it just runs it straight away. you can return a function or better yet, rewrite to:

```
window.addEvent('load', function(){ preloader(preload); });
// or even
window.addEvent('load', preloader.bind(this, preload));
```

Running example:

```js
var imagesArray = new Array(50).join(',').split(',');
imagesArray = imagesArray.map(function(el, i){
    return 'http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/' + (255 - i) + '?' + +new Date();
});

function preloader(images) {
   var img;
   if ( images ) {
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = images[i];
          console.log(img.src);
      }
   }
}

window.addEvent('load', function(){ 
 preloader(imagesArray); 
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.0/mootools-core-full-nocompat.js"></script>
```

You can also have a look at my preloader class which gives you greater flexibility over how your images are pre-loaded, as well as progress etc. https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/pre-loader - it will actually wait for the images to download, allow you to choose how they are loaded etc.

mootools-more also has `Asset.images` you can use.

finally, not sure you want to bind to `load` event, which will trigger when all assets, including images, have been loaded, you should be able to start at `domready` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means, I believe, that mooTools is getting an undefined/malformed parameter in one of your call.

Find out which function is defined at line 4497 of mootools-core.js (can be an object method) and look for each call in your script. Log all parameters/object you're working with, and you'll find your error ;)

**Edit**

Seeing your code, I think your problem come from the fact that `type` is not declared inside condition. Try :

```
if (custom.condition){
            condition = function(event,type){
                if (custom.condition.call(this, event, type)) return fn.call(this, event);
                return true;
            };
```

Comment: Great this is helpful. The error was occurring in the AddEvent method in MooTools, so I'm now debugging.